# adapt script to set IF formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having some difficulty adapting a script I'm using to set a formula, and could use some help please.

The current script I'm using, which sets a simple formula starting in P1, and then every 26th row in Col P is fine, but I want to change the simple =AVL! formula, to an IF formula. The formulas set currently are very simple. For example the first three formulas set are below, and the script sets them in P1, P27, and P53. And so on every 26 rows down to P5175.

```
=AVL!BA3
=AVL!BA4
=AVL!BA5
           Etc down to...
=AVL!BA5175
```

Here's the script for that which is okay...

```
function setFormulas() {

  var sheet, startRow, i; 
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  startRow = 1;
  i = 3;
  while(startRow < 5181) {
    sheet.getRange(startRow, 16).setFormula('=AVL!BA' + i);
    i++;
    startRow += 26;
  }
}
```

I want to change the formula set to set the IF formula below...

```
=IF(AVL!BA3<>"",AVL!BA3,"NO STAFF AVAILABLE!")
=IF(AVL!BA4<>"",AVL!BA4,"NO STAFF AVAILABLE!")
=IF(AVL!BA5<>"",AVL!BA5,"NO STAFF AVAILABLE!")
```

I've tried many different ways now, with no success, but I'm sure it's not hard, just my brain has stalled.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the `setFormula` part to:

`sheet.getRange(startRow, 16).setFormula('=IF(AVL!BA' + i + ' <> "", AVL!BA' + i + ', "NO STAFF AVAILABLE!")');`

Comment: Same thing holds bar the column which I just changed. does it work like this?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help and for teaching me something new!